# Can you remove a UI component from activity when button is clicked?

Tags: android

I am learning Android and working with Android Studio, my question is in the title, can you remove the component? Or you just can only hide it?
For example, I have 2 buttons, first to add the `TextView` component and second to remove it, is it possible to remove that component?

Comment: What is difference between hiding and removing?!

Comment: Use `ViewGroup.removeView` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 1):

you can set visibility of that textView equal View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE like :

```
mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`removeView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#removeView(android.view.View)) in the parent group.

Answer (score 0):

can't remove UI

but can be invisible

```
txt.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

'gone' don't occupy space

'invisible' occupy space

Comment: Are you sure about the "can't remove UI" ?

Comment: i didn't know.. thank you! if i raise my reputation, i will press on useful of your answer